# Stripe Webhook not working

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks

So I'm trying to do a simple Stripe Webhook. Ideally this shouldn't be to difficult.

I'm using this [webhook](https://gist.github.com/boucher/1708172)

So here is my code:

```
  <?php

require_once('lib/Stripe.php');

// Replace "xyz" with your Stripe Secret Live Key //
Stripe::setApiKey("xxx");

$body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event_json = json_decode($body);


// SETUP:
// 1. Customize all the settings (stripe api key, email settings, email text)
// 2. Put this code somewhere where it's accessible by a URL on your server.
// 3. Add the URL of that location to the settings at https://manage.stripe.com/#account/webhooks
// 4. Have fun!
// set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// see your keys here https://manage.stripe.com/account
// retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
$body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event_json = json_decode($body);

// for extra security, retrieve from the Stripe API
$event_id = $event_json->id;
$event = Stripe_Event::retrieve($event_id);

// This will send receipts on succesful invoices
if ($event->type === 'invoice.payment_succeeded') {
    email_invoice_receipt($event->data->object);
}

function email_invoice_receipt($invoice) {
    $customer = Stripe_Customer::retrieve($invoice->customer);

//Make sure to customize your from address
    $subject = 'Your payment has been received';
    $headers = 'From: "MyApp Support" <support@myapp.com>';

    mail($customer->email, $subject, message_body(), $headers);
}

function format_stripe_amount($amount) {
    return sprintf('$%0.2f', $amount / 100.0);
}

function format_stripe_timestamp($timestamp) {
    return strftime("%m/%d/%Y", $timestamp);
}

function payment_received_body($invoice, $customer) {
    $subscription = $invoice->lines->subscriptions[0];
    return <<<EOF
Dear {$customer->email}:

This is a receipt for your subscription. This is only a receipt,
 no payment is due. Thanks for your continued support!
-------------------------------------------------
SUBSCRIPTION RECEIPT

Email: {$customer->email}
Plan: {$subscription->plan->name}
Amount: {format_stripe_amount($invoice->total)} (USD)

For service between {format_stripe_timestamp($subscription->period->start)} and {format_stripe_timestamp($subscription->period->end)}

-------------------------------------------------

EOF;
}

?>
```

The sign up page is here: http://www.strategic-options.com/trade/sign_up
Webhook here: http://www.strategic-options.com/trade/3_party/Simple-Bootstrap-Stripe-Payment-Form/stripe_webhook.php

My transactions are going thru, casue I see them in the dashboard. I have set the webhook on the dashboard appropriately to the right link. So when I try to test on webhook feature I always get a fail because evt_000000000 doesn't get a response. I don't know of any other way to test this webhook, other than the using the dashboard?

```
<br/>
<b>Fatal error</b>: Uncaught exception 'Stripe_InvalidRequestError' with message 'No such event: evt_00000000000000' in /home/strategicoptions/strategic-options.com/trade/3_party/Simple-Bootstrap-Stripe-Payment-Form/lib/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php:152
Stack trace:
#0 /home/strategicoptions/strategic-options.com/trade/3_party/Simple-Bootstrap-Stripe-Payment-Form/lib/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php(212): Stripe_ApiRequestor-&gt;handleApiError('{\n &quot;error&quot;: {\n...', 404, Array)
#1 /home/strategicoptions/strategic-options.com/trade/3_party/Simple-Bootstrap-Stripe-Payment-Form/lib/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php(114): Stripe_ApiRequestor-&gt;_interpretResponse('{\n &quot;error&quot;: {\n...', 404)
#2 /home/strategicoptions/strategic-options.com/trade/3_party/Simple-Bootstrap-Stripe-Payment-Form/lib/Stripe/ApiResource.php(24): Stripe_ApiRequestor-&gt;request('get', '/v1/events/evt_...', Array)
#3 /home/strategicoptions/strategic-options.com/trade/3_party/Simple-Bootstrap-Stripe-Payment-Form/lib/Stripe/ApiResource.php(8): Stripe_ApiResource-&gt;refresh()
#4 /home/strategicop in <b>/home/strategicoptions/strategic-options.com/trade/3_party/Simple-Bootstrap-Stripe-Payment-Form/lib/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php</b> on line <b>152</b><br/>
```

Answer (score 7):

The issue here is that the event you are trying to retrieve through the API `evt_00000000000000` doesn't exist in your account which is why it fails.

When you use the "Send test webhook..." button in the dashboard it simply sends a generic event with fake data in it. All the identifiers would have `0` into it so there is no way to retrieve it through the [Retrieve Event API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_event).

What you need to do here instead is use real events in your account. To do that, you can simply create a customer or a charge in the dashboard in Test mode which would automatically send the event `customer.created` or `charge.created` to your webhook endpoint and the code should then work as expected.

Answer (score 6):

### I solved it by using ngrok:

1. **Install [ngrok](https://ngrok.com)**
2. **Create a tunnel** to localhost by running `ngrok http {local_port}`
3. You will see **two public urls**(http and https) which will forward to your local port

[image]

4. **Login** to stripe and **create a webhook** where the url will be the url displayed by ngrok

[image]

5. **Create** the endpoint and **send** test webhook.
6. **Boom**! Problem solved.
7. That means you can now send test webhook that gets received by localhost. If you see the event id is `evt_00000000000000`, just don't validate it by retrieving from stripe, otherwise validate it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running on stripe sandbox make sure to add these on your .env file.

```
STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
CASHIER_ENV=testing
```